# What is the meaning of $\mathbb R^+$?

Tags: notation

For a function $f$ that maps set $A$ to $B$,

- $f\colon\mathbb R^+\to\mathbb R^+$, $f(x) = x^2$ is injective.
- $f\colon\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$, $f(x) = x^2$ is not injective since $(- x)^2 = x^2$.

what is the difference between $\mathbb R^+$ and $\mathbb R$?

Additionally, what is the difference between $\mathbb N$ and $\mathbb N^+$?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

$\mathbb R^+$ commonly denotes the set of positive real numbers, that is: $$\mathbb R^+ = \{x\in\mathbb R\mid x>0\}$$

It is also denoted by $\mathbb R^{>0},\mathbb R_+$ and so on.

For $\mathbb N$ and $\mathbb N^+$ the difference is similar, however it may be non-existent if you define $0\notin\mathbb N$. In many set theory books $0$ is a natural number, while in analysis it is often not considered a natural number. Your mileage may vary on $\mathbb N$ vs. $\mathbb N^+$.

Comment: I see now. I thought it meant that R+ included some extra element. This interpretation makes much more sense.

Comment: Note that $\mathbb N^+ = \mathbb Z^+$. Also if you want to confuse your readers, you can write the empty set as $\mathbb N^-$, the set of negative natural numbers. :-)

Comment: NB : Depending on the country, $\mathbb R^+$ is also used for the set of non-negative real numbers.

Comment: @Student: Really? $0\in\mathbb R^+$? Sounds bizarre!

Comment: @Asaf: as Ranabir says in a separate answer, it makes sense for $\mathbb{R}^+$ to be the set of positive reals. In some countries "positive" includes zero.  Compare Willie Wong's answer to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26705/is-zero-positive-or-negative

Comment: @Carl: Read the first line, I also say it defines the positive numbers. I just never thought zero is positive... :-) (Also, these French just have to do everything the other way around...! :-))

Comment: I was taught that $\mathbb{R}^+$ is the set of positive real numbers greater than $0$ and $\mathbb{R}_+ = \{(x, y)\in\mathbb{R} : x,y\geqslant 0\}$.

Comment: @user477343: I didn't know that the elements of $\Bbb R$ are intervals, or ordered pairs... Since they are not, $\Bbb R_+$ as you defined it would be just $\varnothing$.

Comment: Go here $\longrightarrow$ https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/263175/what-does-the-notation-mathbb-r2-mean?rq=1

Comment: @user477343: If only there was a difference between $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb R^2$...

Comment: It implies for all $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: @user477343: I don't understand you, and your notation is not consistent. So I'm going to stop replying now. Have a great day!

Answer (score 6):

Simply $\mathbb R$ means the set of real numbers.

$\mathbb R^+$ means the set of positive real numbers.

And $\mathbb R^-$ means the set of negative real numbers.