# What does the notation $\mathbb R^2_{++}$ mean?

Tags: notation

Can anyone tell me what $\mathbb R^2_{++}$ means?
Is it different from $\mathbb R^2_+$?

Thank you so much!

Edit (answer):
This is what the author meant (I found it in the lecture notes by the same professor but of a different course): $\mathbb R^2_{++}=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2\mid x>0, y>0\}$ , while $\mathbb R^2_+=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2\mid x≥0, y≥0\}$ .

Comment: Please confirm that I LaTeX'd your notation properly.

Comment: yes, that's exactly what i meant. thank you

Comment: What do you think $\mathbb{R}^2_+$ means? (It's not entirely obvious.) My guess would be that $\mathbb{R}^2_{++}$ is supposed to denote $(\mathbb{R}_+)^2$, i.e. the set of points $(x,y)$ where both coordinates are positive, but check the text where you found it. There is probably a definition somewhere (at least, there should be). I have never seen this notation before.

Comment: @mrf: I've used that notation $\mathbb{R}^2_{++}$ previously (and privately only). It is somewhat useful in convex analysis when sometimes one has to consider individual orthants, and so $\mathbb{R}^n_{+++---+\cdots +}$ can be useful sometimes to keep track of the combinatorics. On the other hand, I don't ever use $\mathbb{R}^2_+$: if I want a half-space I call it $\mathbb{R}_+\times \mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: As a follow up: in 2D there is a usual convention for numbering the quadrants. (Though I often forget which is second and which is fourth.) But in higher dimensions I am not aware of any established numbering convention...

Answer (score 4):

This is not a usual notation, so it should probably be mentioned somewhere, but a reasonable guess would be $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2\mid x>0, y>0\}$.

If you supply more context, and in particular *where* you have seen this notation perhaps further information can be given.

Comment: It comes from an example of utility functions.

Comment: Again, more details on where you found that example will help. (Note that "in a book" or "online" is not a helpful expansion of current knowledge of the whereabouts of this example.)

Comment: It comes from an example of utility functions. Let u:R^2_+ --> R such that u(x)=(a*(x_1)^b+(1-a)(x_2)^b)^(1/b) with a in [0,1] anb b in (0,1]. Let v:R^2_++ -->R such that v(x)=(x_1)^c*(x_2)^(1-c) with c in [0,1]. This example should show that this 2 utility functions have different domain.

Comment: I found it in some lecture notes, there is no way to ask directly to the professor who wrote it.

Comment: @babbonatale: Asaf's point is that "details about where you found that example" means **tell us the author and title of the book**, preferrably plus edition and page number.

Comment: The point is that there is no book at all. That is why I am so confused. I thought it was a common notation, but I see this is not the case.

Comment: @babbonatale: But *where* did you find those lecture notes? If you took them from a friend, ask the friend, if you found them online ask whoever posted them to add the information to the notes. First, however, you should look more carefully in the notes.

Comment: Okay I'll do that. At least now I know this is not a widely accepted notation. Thank you very much.