# Notation for $\{n\in\mathbb{Z}:n\ge m\}$ for a given $m\in\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: notation

Is there a standard notation for the set of integers which are greater than or equal to a fixed integer $m$?

Comment: Maybe this one $\mathbb Z_{\geqslant m}$?

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}_{\ge m}$ works. Probably you'll be using a lot, and that's why you ask, For good measure, define it once then use it freely. "I'll use the abbreviation $\mathbb{Z}_{\ge m} = \{n\in\mathbb{Z}:n\ge m\}$".

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}\setminus I_{m-1}$?

Comment: @LuisFelipe Where does the notation $I_{m-1}$ come from? I've never seen it before...

Comment: @A.P. Really? it comes from Elon Lages Lima, real analysis book's. 
$I_m:=\{n\in\mathbb{N}:n\leq m\}$

Comment: @LuisFelipe: Isn't $\mathbb{Z} \setminus I_{m - 1} = \mathbb{Z}_{≥m} ∪ \mathbb{Z}_{<0}$?

Comment: @user87690 I can not edit my first post. It must say: $\mathbb{Z}^+\setminus I_{m-1}$

Answer (score 2):

Collecting all comments together (to push it out of unanswered queue):

1. $\Bbb Z_{\ge m}$
2. $\Bbb Z^+ \text\I_{m-1}$, where $I_m:=\{n\in\Bbb N: n\le m\}$, from Real Analysis by Elon Lages Lima.

Quoting following similar questions (on $\Bbb R$):

1. [How does one denote the set of all positive real numbers?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/27968/45937)
2. [Correct notation for “for all positive real $c$”](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1476125/45937)