# Prove by contradiction that a real number that is less than every positive real number cannot be posisitve

Tags: reference-request, self-learning

This is an question from the book "A concise introduction to Pure Mathematics". I understand that it looks like a homework question but it's the first chapter and there are no answers for even questions. As I am independently trying to make my way through a bit of maths I was hoping I could get some help.

The real reason I am stumped is I don't yet have a firm grasp on what a proof is (at which point its conclusively proven).

I think the negation of the statement would be

"There exists a real number less than every positive real number that is positive"

I am tempted to use square root and say

n > 0

n = sqrt(k)

therefore k > 0

I don't think I have proven anything.

Also: **Could someone please advise and perhaps throw some beginner texts my way?**

Thank you

Comment: You might be better off asking for books in a separate question.

Comment: Though to address "knowing what a proof is", I personally learned formal proof techniques from Quine's "Methods of Logic", which is a fine introduction if you want to *do* logic instead of study it. That said, most "proofs" are informal sketches meant to persuade a reader that a truly formal proof *could* be done. Reading instances of this latter kind is your best bet.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Perhaps easier: if $\;\epsilon>0\;$ is less than any positive number, then **also**

$$\epsilon<\frac\epsilon2\;,\;\;\text{since also}\;\;\frac\epsilon2>0\;\;\;\ldots\;\;\text{contradiction}$$

Answer (score 17):

Suppose that $x$ is a real number less than every positive number. Suppose to the contrary that $x$ is positive. Then $x>x$.

Answer (score 3):

I would like to point out that the answer to your question depends very much on the exact phrasing. I very much doubt that the question you posted is 1:1 the question in the book.

In some regions of the world, *cough* e.g. Germany as well as France, zero is considered to be both positive and negative at the same time, see for instance here: [Is zero positive or negative?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26705/is-zero-positive-or-negative)

In fact, if zero is considered positive, then there exists a real number that is smaller than every *other* positive real number and still positive, namely zero.

Why I'm pointing this out is the following: Were the question states as you posted it here, i.e. "Prove by contradiction that a real number that is less than every positive real number cannot be positive."

Then the proof is simple, because
$$
\forall x \in \mathbb{R}: \neg (x \lt x)
$$

So the number in your question would have to be smaller than itself in order to fulfill the stated requirement anyway, which clearly does not hold.