# Prove without method of contradiction that there exists a real number less than every positive real number that is positive

Tags: alternative-proof

This question was asked before for proof by contradiction and which got me into thinking whether i could prove it without using a contradiction

Original problem statement is here
[Prove by contradiction that a real number that is less than every positive real number cannot be posisitve](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/566781/prove-by-contradiction-that-a-real-number-that-is-less-than-every-positive-real)

**Question**

There exists a real number less than every positive real number that is positive

With using the method of contradiction it can be easily proved. But without?

Here's what i tried

$$
\text{let} \space \exists \space a \in \Re \text{ such that } \forall \epsilon > 0 \space a < \epsilon
$$

now we can write it as

$$
\epsilon \, - a > 0 \\
but \, \epsilon - a \in \Re+ \\
hence \, (\epsilon - a) - a > 0 \rightarrow \epsilon - 2a > 0 \\
\; \rightarrow \frac{\epsilon}{2} > a \\
similarly \, \frac{\epsilon}{n} > a \, where \, n \in \Re+
$$

from here onwards, i showed that when n goes to positive infinity, the whole term goes to 0 which makes $ 0 > a $

but i'm not sure how correct that is. Any ideas? :)

And also my apologies for poor formatting of equations, it's my first time with the tex

Comment: Well first, only nonstrict inequalities are preserved under limits, so taking limits gives only $a \leq 0$, not $a < 0$. Second, you may need to justify the preservation of nonstrict inequalities. This depends on who you are writing this for. Shorter proofs might exist depending on how you are defining $\mathbb{R}$ (for instance, you might be able to get a short proof by using the Archimedean property of $\mathbb{Q}$).

Comment: yes i got the $ a < 0 $ result and stuck from there :/ this was a university assigment, well the original question was the thread i have posted as a link above, this is just for my curiosity whether it's possible

Comment: Even if right, it still seems to be a proof by contradiction.

Comment: @coffeemath since i didnt contradict any of the original facts or premises i thought this would be a varying approach

Comment: Your final conclusion, which should be that $a \le 0$ rather than $a<0$ [see Ian's comment] is to the initial assumption that $a>0$ and so is a contradiction to that assumption. Actually in your initial start you only assumed for all $epsilon>0$ that $a<\epsilon,$ without the assumption that $a>0$ But if the assumption $a>0$ is dropped, you can't get a contradiction anyway since maybe for example the initial $a$ is $-1$.

Comment: You are asking for a real number which is less than itself. No epsilons needed to see that such a number does not exist.

Comment: @coffeemath sorry but i didnt get the last part, because i didnot specifically assumed $ a > 0 $ in the beginning, and only got $ a < 0 $ as a result. Will that still be a contradiction?

Comment: OK you have $\epsilon>0$ and $a<\epsilon$ so you do get $\epsilon-a>0.$ In the next line the step is to subtract $a$ from each side, and you conclude that $\epsilon-2a>0.$ However from $\epsilon-a>0$ after subtracting the $a$ the result may be negative, not positive. Consider the case of $\epsilon=1,\ a=0.9.$ Then $\epsilon-a=0.1$ but $\epsilon-2a=-0.8$ is negative, going against your conclusion that $\epsilon-2a>0$ at that point.

Comment: @coffeemath ahh got it, thankxx :) so there's no way other than contradiction to prove this?

Comment: Manzup: I don't think without contradiction creeping in. Even using the least upper bound property, some kind of contradiction argument is used to show that an element of a set is less than or equal to its least upper bound.

Comment: @coffeemath since ManZzup assumed $a$ was the 'smallest' positive real number , so   $(\epsilon-a)-a=\epsilon-2a>0$ is reasonable .

Comment: @ManZzup If $\lim _{x\rightarrow \infty }a_{n}=a$ and $\lim _{x\rightarrow \infty }b_{n}=b$, and there exists a number $N > 0$ such that $a_{n}\leq b_{n}$ for all  $n>N$, then $a\leq b$ . You should know this in order to get $a \le 0$ rather than $a<0$.