# Intersection of sets of positive integers divisible by n

Tags: real-analysis

This is a question from the set theory section of Kolmogorov & Fomin's *Introductory Real Analysis*

Let $A_n$ be the set of positive integers divisible by $n$,  find the set $$\bigcap\limits_{n=2}^\infty A_n.$$

I would think that the answer is $\{0\}$, but I don't know if $0$ is considered a positive integer in this context.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: $0$ is not a positive integer in any context. It is sometimes considered a natural number.

Comment: @Joffan I was referring to [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/26708/346958) answer, which says that zero is positive (and negative) in typical French usage.

Comment: @Elliot I don't understand your comment.  Do you mean the answer is not 0?

Comment: I was trying to think of the name... the [law of trichotomy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trichotomy_(mathematics)) - *Every real number is either negative, zero, or positive*. --- As for the French usage, I'm guessing that the book you refer to is not written in French.

Comment: It was originally written in Russian, and having read that about French usage it seemed reasonable not to make the assumption it is not the case in Russian.

Comment: If you consider 0 to be positive (which no-one does) the answer is {0} if you do not consider zero to be positive the answer is the empty set.  There's no profundity to the answer either way.  If A_n were defined to be all integers, or all Natural numbers or all Natural numbers including zero the answers would have different answers but relevent "moral" would be the same: 0 is the only integer that is divisible by all non-zero integers.

Comment: "I would think that the answer is {0}, but I don't know if 0 is considered a positive integer in this context." So what do you think the answer would be if 0 *isn't* considered a positive integer (which it isn't)?

Answer (score 2):

$$\bigcap\limits_{n=2}^\infty A_n=∅$$ because there is no any positive integer that is divisible by all integers without a remainder.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews thanks for the correction

Answer (score 0):

0 is not positive.

$A_i \subset \mathbb Z^+$ so $\cap A_n \subset \mathbb Z^+$

Let $k \in \mathbb Z^+$.  $k + 1$ does not divide $k$.  So $k \not \in A_{n+1}$ so $k \not \in \cap A_n$.  So $\cap A_n$ contains no positive integers but contains nothing else either.

So $\cap A_n = \emptyset$.

Let $n \ge 2$