# A Criteria of Diophantine Equations on one variable, Is it wrong?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility, diophantine-equations

The following is a Home Work question provided by our instructor:

> let a,b,c be positive integers. Prove that if a+b>c then the equation
>   ax+by = c has no solutions in positive integers.

I think the statement is *false* since $4x+12y=4$ is a counter example. However, it is wired that a home work question be formulated that way. Or, did I miss something?

Comment: What is the solution to $4x+12y=4$ in _positive_ integers?

Comment: @Wojowu The solutions is :x = 1, y = 0.

Comment: $0$ is not positive.

Comment: $ax+by \geq a+b$ for all $x,y>0$.

Comment: you are trying to say that the statement is true though.

Comment: Yes, the statement _is_ true.

Comment: @Wojowu, any hints to prove?

Comment: @MagedSaeed isn't my comment the hint that you need?

Comment: Anurag already gave a hint (except it should've had $\geq$, not $>$)

Comment: @AnuragA I thing you are clarifying something. I will try to have a second deep look. Thanks,,

Comment: @AnuragA Thanks, I just got it..

Comment: @Wojowu In fact $0$ is "positive" in some languages.

Comment: @BillDubuque: I've heard of zero being considered as a natural number at times, but never positive. What language(s)? Do you have a reference?

Comment: @RghtHndSd e.g. [French.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/26708/242)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instructor is interested in positive integers,which are {1,2,3,4,....}

If $ a+b>c$ and $x\ge 1$ and $y\ge 1$, then $ax+by \ge a+b >c$

Thus the equality does not happen, that is there is no solution in positive integers.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.