# What will accepting 1 as prime change?

Tags: prime-numbers

How significant is the fact 1 isn't a prime number? What will happen if it is?
What areas of Mathematics are affected by changing the fact?
I know why and how 1 isn't a prime. My question is how significant is the fact.

Comment: Since $1^n = 1$, there is no longer a unique prime factorization of any integer, and pretty much the whole of number theory will fall apart unless you change "prime" to "prime $\ne 1$" virtually everywhere.

Comment: It will make theorems more annoying to state.

Comment: See the answers in [Why is $1$ not a prime number?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/120/242)

Comment: I know why and how 1 isn't a prime. My question is how significant is the fact.

Comment: What do you mean by "changing the fact"? Facts in math  are not a matter of personal opinion. If you change the definition of a prime number to make 1 a prime, you can't then say "well, I know it isn't a prime really".

Comment: HaHa...Maybe I could've, if the definition was the changed one.

Comment: It's analogous to asking what will change if we allow $0$ to be positive (as [the French do](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/26708/242)). Many theorems using "positive" would need to be updated to remain correct.

Comment: It would changed the fact, that in geometry, length is the most extended dimension of an object.

Comment: @usiro: I did not get your point.

Comment: Basically $1$ is a unit and cannot be represented as a line.

Comment: @usiro I can't make any sense of your remarks. In any case notions such as irreducible, prime and unit are independent of geometry.

Comment: @BillDubuque That's ok - the above are my thoughts, not the answer. Every prime greater than $7$ can be formed as a sum of two rectangles minus their intersection - therefore a prime itself cannot be formed as a rectangle.

Answer (score 2):

That wouldn't be a disaster, but it would add some very annoying things. For example, instead of the uniqueness in the fundamental theorem of arithmetic we would have "uniqueness up to finitely many multiplications of $1$".

Comment: We can have infinitely many 1's too, right?

Comment: Actually yes, we can. But even if we want to say that every integer can be represented as a finite product of primes it would still not be a unique decomposition.

Comment: There wouldn't be any uniqueness.Got your point.

Comment: @Krishna No, infinite products don't make sense in general (one needs additional ring structure to make sense of them).

Comment: additional ring structure?

Answer (score 0):

We need factorisation of positive integers to be *unique* in many contexts, and this fails if we take $1$ to be prime, since then $6,$ for example, would factorise in the infinity of ways $$2×3=2×3×\underbrace{1×1×\cdots×1}_{n},$$ where $n$ is a nonnegative integer. This happens for the other positive integers too.

Actually, $1$ is different from the other positive integers in that it is neither composite nor prime. This distinguished position follows from the fact that $1$ is the multiplicative identity in $\mathbf Z;$ that is, for any integer $m,$ we have that $$1×m=m×1=m.$$