# $\mathbb{Z}^{+}$ includes zero or not?

Tags: definition, natural-numbers

Does $\mathbb{Z}^{+}$ includes zero or not? I think that $0$ is not involved in the set of positive integers, but my book included zero in the set of positive integers in an answer.

Comment: You can count it as the book's authours' mistake, zero is not a positive integer.

Comment: Oh, so basically when we define integers, we can categorise the set of integers into 3 sub-categories : $$\begin{align} & \bullet \mathbb{Z}^{+} \implies \text{Positive Integers only.} \\ & \bullet \mathbb{Z}^{-} \implies \text{Negative Integers only.} \\ & \bullet 0 \implies \text{Zero only.} \end{align} $$ 

is this right?

Comment: If I was decorating $\mathbf{Z}$ to describe the nonnegative integers, I would write $\mathbf{Z}^{\geq}$ or $\mathbf{Z}^{\geq 0}$. It is a quirk of English language (or at least, English usage) that the word "positive" is not well-defined on whehter or not it includes $0$.

Comment: While I consider **non-negative** and **positive** are actually different terms.

Comment: @Kusha: I agree that *should* be true, but one must be aware of how the word "positive" gets actually used, because one will encounter people who use the word positive when they mean nonnegative.

Comment: Very right @Hurkyl , I agree with you!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A number $x$ is defined to be positive if $x > 0$. Is $0 > 0$? No, so it is non-positive (and it is also non-negative).

$\mathbb Z^+$ is a notation, so it is difficult to argue about it, because *some* authors do use non-standard notation and it's alright as long as they're consistent. But $\mathbb Z^+_0$ is a better notation for the set of non-negative integers.

Comment: @KushashwaRaviShrimali Adding to the confusion, some textbooks include $0$ in the set of natural numbers $\mathbb N$, whereas others don't, and use $\mathbb N_0$ for $\mathbb N \cup \{0\}$. Personally, I don't include $0$ in $\mathbb N$, and this also seems to be the convention followed by the majority.

Comment: Yeah, well, Natural Numbers are basically defined as $$\{ 1,2,3, \dots\} $$

Comment: @Kushahwa: In many places the natural numbers do include $0$. This is why they are usually denoted by $\Bbb N$ and not by $\Bbb Z^+$.

Comment: @M.Vinay: It is easy to judge the "majority" if you haven't seen it. I could claim the same, since in my field $0$ is a natural number. So in all the books, and all the papers and all the classes... $0$ was always a natural number.

Answer (score 5):

As some of the answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18464/is-positive-the-same-as-non-negative) show, in some languages the term "positive" may include $0$. In particular, it might be expected that authors whose native tongue is such a language may include $0$ in $\Bbb Z^+$.

If the book is consistent with this definition, then there's no real issue here. If the book suddenly becomes inconsistent with this definition (e.g. the author writes $\frac1n$ for $n\in\Bbb Z^+$) then it is likely a typo.