# Why do we say a non-negative real number

Tags: proof-writing, terminology, article-writing

In some articles, we write "non-negative real number". Why we don't simply say "positive real number" ?

Comment: Non-negative: $x \geq 0$. Positive: $x > 0$. Non-negative is slightly shorter than "positive or zero".

Comment: $0$ is not positive and many times you want to include it.

Comment: In French, zero is included in the positive numbers, so sometimes they would have to say 'non-zero positive number'.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1740775