# Show that there exists a constant $c>0$ so that $f(n) \le cg(n)$ for every $n\ge 1$

Tags: asymptotics

Given two positive functions $f(n)$,$g(n)$, such that $f(n)=O(g(n))$ (big O notation) show that there exists a constant $c>0$ so that $f(n)\le cg(n)$ for every $n\ge1$

I dont know how to solve this because I learned at class that $n$ can start start from any number.

For example if $g(n)=\log n$ it can't start from $n=1$ because $\log 1=0$

Comment: I forgot the O , thanks

Comment: So what is your definition of $f(n)=O(g(n))$?

Comment: tf(n)=O(g(n)) (big O notation) if exists a constant c>0 ; and a $n_1\in Naturals$ so that for
 $n>n_1$ f(n)<=c∗g(n)

Comment: so your definition is that $f \in \mathcal O(g)$ iff $\exists c \in \mathbb R, N \in \mathbb N$ such that $f(n) \le cg(n)$ for all $n > N$. Now, the definition in your post clearly implies this. To show the converse, choose a $c$ that works for all $n > N$, and think of how you can choose a bigger constant $c'$ such that $f(n) \le c' g(n)$ is guaranteed for all $1 \le n \le N$

Answer (score 1):

Let $f,g$ be positive and such that $f(n) = O(g(n))$ (as $n\to\infty$). By definition of $O(\cdot)$, there exists $N\geq 1$ and $C>0$ such that $f(n) \leq C\cdot g(n)$ for all $n \geq N$.

So how to deal with $1\leq n < N$? Well, you only have a finite number of them, so you can "incorporate that in the constant," separately. Set
$$
C' \stackrel{\rm def}{=} \max\!\left(C, \frac{f(1)}{g(1)}, \frac{f(2)}{g(2)},\dots, \frac{f(N-1)}{g(N-1)}\right)
$$
This is indeed a constant, positive. Moreover, for every $n\geq 1$:

- if $n \geq N$, then $f(n) \leq C\cdot g(n) \leq C' \cdot g(n)$, since $C' \geq C$.
- if $n < N$, then $f(n) = \frac{f(n)}{g(n)}\cdot g(n) \leq C' \cdot g(n)$, since $C' \geq \frac{f(n)}{g(n)}$.

Therefore, you have what you want: there exists a constant $C'>0$ such that $f(n) \leq C'\cdot g(n)$ for all $n\geq 1$.

**Remark:** we used the fact that $g$ is *positive* ($g(n) > 0$ for all $n$) to avoid division by $0$ when we define $C'$.

Answer (score 0):

Let me repeat your sentence:

$f,g \geqslant 0$ and $f=O(g)$. Exist or not such $C>0$, that $f(n) \leqslant C \cdot g(n)$ for $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$?

Answer is no, because big-O does not set restriction on some initial segment of $\mathbb{N}$.
Let's define

$ f(n) =
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
    1  & \mbox{if } n = 1 \\
    0 & \mbox{if  } n > 1
\end{array}
\right. $

and let's take $g(n) = 0,\ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$, then $f(n) \leqslant g(n)$ for $n > 1$.

Then, obviously, we have $f=O(g)$, but for any $C>0$ we have $1=f(1)>C \cdot g(1) = 0$.

Of course, if we consider $f>0$ functions, then, this contr example do not work and we can find $C>0$ for any $n$.

But also here we can make proof in less restrictions, then $f>0$. Let's call kernel of function set $ ker (f) = \left\lbrace n: f(n)=0 \right\rbrace = f^{-1}(0) $.

Now consider again $f,g \geqslant 0$ and $f=O(g)$. If $ker( f) = ker (g)$, then we can find $C>0$ such that for any $n$ $f(n) \leqslant C \cdot g(n)$ .

Comment: "Positive" means you can't have $g(n)=0$.

Comment: @Clement C. Firstly: it depends on source used. Look, please, at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_(mathematics) and find  "Terminology for signs" and there "strictly positive" vs "positive". Different sources may use different terminology. Second: of course, for $f>0$ functions my example not work.

Comment: I am French, where "positif" means $\geq 0$. I am aware of the differences between languages. All I'm saying is that the standard meaning of "positive" in English, in a mathematical context, is $>0$. The same way that "greater" means $>$, not $\geq$.

Comment: Same is for "greater" vs "strict greater", again is possible to look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strict . I did not see standards in this case  - some authors use one definition, others another. It's, of course, not very convenient.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18464/is-positive-the-same-as-non-negative, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_real_numbers, etc. Anyways.

Comment: Anyways it doesn't create "standard". I more value mathematical results, even little: I add some generalization to $f>0$ case. More nice is to make next step, no?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108755/discussion-between-zkutch-and-clement-c).